# using "if"'s in jQuery tmpl

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

Is it possible to create `if` sentences inside a jQuery tmpl template?

```
<script id="template" type="text/html">
    <h1>${someVar}</h1>
    if (${intro}!="")
        <small>${intro}</small>
    endif
    <p>${restOfVariables}</p>
</script>
```

Now, this would only write out the if as text, so is there any way to do something like this? Or would I have to create two different templates and do the check in my js before calling the template?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to [these docs](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/templating-syntax), you can do:

```
<script id="template" type="text/html">
    <h1>${someVar}</h1>
    {{if intro != ""}}
        <small>${intro}</small>
    {{/if}}
    <p>${restOfVariables}</p>
</script>
```

Comment: Aagh you had a 14 second lead! OK fine I'll delete my basically-identical answer...

Comment: Nice! But Resig's `tmpl` file crashed on me with if/else statements. Found this fork on github that fixed the issue, though: http://github.com/jchadwick/jquery-tmpl

Comment: FYI, you can't have a space between the {{ and if.